# Class doesn't autoload if method is called through a variable

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to pass variables as references to a static method called through a string, therefore I cannot use `call_user_func` or `call_user_func_array` (no reference).

As shown [in this example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php#78949), I wanted to simply call the function through its variable's name:

```
$f = '\\bbn\\appui\\history::trigger';
if ( is_callable($f) ){
  $tmp = $f($table, $kind, $moment, $values, $where);
}
```

And I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function \bbn\appui\history::trigger()

So it is callable, but undefined?? And what's funny is that if I change $f to:

```
'\\\\bbn\\\\appui\\\\history::trigger'
```

(don't ask me why I tried!), I get:

> Fatal error: include(): Cannot redeclare class bbn\appui\history

This function is called as the callback of another, so it's very important for me that it is called through a variable. Anybody would have an idea how to get it working?

I use Composer and its autoload class, all my classes are psr-0, and I have no problem whatsoever with them auto-loading.

Comment: You don't want to call the function, but static method of class. One of differences between them is that second one can not be called directly as you are trying to do. You need `call_user_func` for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running PHP **5.3.x** it is possible with [`ReflectionMethod::invoke`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php):

```
$f = '\\bbn\\appui\\history::trigger';
list($class, $method) = explode('::', $f);
$rm = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
$rm->invoke(null, &$myvar);
```

If you have newer PHP version, `eval` seems to be only option...

Comment: The real problem here is that it is a static call. One should have an instance of that object and then call the trigger method, and everything works. That way it could be very dynamic if needed.

Comment: It is a callback used in a class and has vocation to be any kind of function/static method but not an existing object: the function is called before anything else. I use 5.4 and will go soon to 5.5. No way I can use eval there for security reasons but I think I found an alternative where I can use `call_user_func` because I wouldn't need the reference anymore. But it's a pity this doens't work: considering the errors I'm getting it really looks like an autolad flaw than PHP itself.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea why autoloader is triggered in your second example. You can [simplify your example to not namespaced class declaration and calling it in one file](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZEm2pa) with same result.